# Perl: How to iterate through symbol table to find all loaded subclasses of Foo::Bar?

Tags: perl, exception, subclassing, symbol-tables

I have a module which is defining exceptions for the package of which it is a part.  The exceptions are being declared with `Exception::Class::Nested`.

For purposes of discussion, let's say that this module is named `Foo::Bar::Exception`, and that all of the exceptions it defines are first-level subclasses of that  (*e.g.*, `Foo::Bar::Exception:DoNotDoThat`).  All of the exceptions I care about are defined in this module file; I'm not interested in any additional subclassing any other module does of me.

For my `import` method, I want to construct a list of all the exceptions being defined, and I'd like to do it by traversing the symbol table somehow rather than keeping a hard-coded list that can get out of sync with the definitions and has to be manually maintained.

So, how can `Foo::Bar::Exception->import` iterate through `Foo::Bar::Exception`'s symbol table to find all the exceptions (first-level subclasses) that have been declared in the module?  It's just the active loaded symbol table I'm interested in; no filesystem searches or the like.

Thanks!

[*addendum*]

Since all of my exception subclass names end with `Exception` or `Error`, this looks like it's getting close to what I want:

```
my %symtable = eval("'%' . __PACKAGE__ . '::'");
my @shortnames = grep(m!(?:Error|Exception)::$!, keys(%symtable));
@shortnames = ( map { $_ =~ s/::$//; $_; } @shortnames );
my @longnames = ( map { __PACKAGE__ . '::' . $_ } @shortnames );
```

Some of the parenthesisation is unnecessary, but I added it for clarity about the array context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol table for `Foo::Bar::Exception` is `%Foo::Bar::Exception::`, so you could write:

```
sub import {
    for my $key (keys %Foo::Bar::Exception::) {
        if (my ($name) = $key =~ /(.+)::$/) {
           my $pkg = 'Foo::Bar::Exception::'.$name;
           no strict 'refs';
           *{caller()."::$name"} = sub () {$pkg};
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use MRO::Compat;
my @classes = @{ mro::get_isarev("Foo::Bar::Exception") };
@classes = grep $_->isa("Foo::Bar::Exception"), @classes;
```

[MRO::Compat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/MRO%3a%3aCompat) enables the [mro](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/ext/mro/mro.pm) API on pre-5.10 perls that otherwise wouldn't have it (although `get_isarev` is *much* faster on 5.10+), `get_isarev` returns classes that inherit (directly or indirectly) from the named class, and the final grep is because `get_isarev` is a heuristic sort of function -- it will never *miss* a class that does inherit the one you specified, but in the face of runtime `@ISA` modification it might report a class that actually *doesn't* inherit your class anymore. So the `->isa` check makes sure that the class is still there and still a subclass.

*Edit:* just noticed the part where you're only interested in packages that are under the namespace as well, but I still think that using the mro API is a good foundation for finding them -- just tack on a `grep /^Foo::Bar::Exception::/` as well :)

Comment: I get a `Can't call method "isa" on unblessed reference` on the `grep`, so something in `@classes` is unblessed.  This is Perl v5.10.1.

Just checked: `@classes` is getting set to an empty arrayref, `[]`.

Comment: Oops. missing dereference. Edited. But if it's empty then your inheritance isn't set up properly.

Comment: The inheritance *should* be getting set up by `Exception::Class` or `Exception::Class::Nested`, since they're what are actually creating the packages/classes.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the inheritance issues (apparently introduced by `Exception::Class` or `Exception::Class::Nested`), I've gone with the pure symbol-table route.

Both the longnames (*e.g.*, `Foo::Bar::Exception:DoNotDoThat`) and the shortnames (`DoNotDoThat`) are exportable; the longnames are exported by default.  (Unclear if that's necessary, but it seems to do no harm.)

If the shortnames are being exported, this does the trick:

```
my $caller = caller();
$caller ||= 'main';
my @snames = @{$EXPORT_TAGS{shortnames}};
for my $short (@snames) {
    my $exc = __PACKAGE__ . '::' . $short;
    no strict 'refs';
    *{"$caller\::$short"} = sub () { $exc };
}
```

which is quite close to @Eric's answer, but derived before I saw his.

Thanks, everyone!